# Anaconda Python3 - ipython returns an empty dictionary when given two lists

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I have the following code to convert 2 lists into a dictionary using zip function in the ipython notebook:

```
>>> dishes = ["pizza", "sauerkraut", "paella", "Hamburger"]
>>> countries = ["Italy", "Germany", "Spain", "USA"]
>>> country_specialities = zip(countries, dishes)
>>> dict(country_specialities)
{}
```

But everything works fine in the python-3 interpreter. Can someone tell me why this is happening? Here are the details of my ipython instance:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

Comment: I just observed that if I import the collections package and then force the conversion, it returns an empty dictionary. I guess there is some conflict.

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible example (with all imports) and also check if you can reproduce the problem after restarting the kernel.

Comment: Here's the link to the notebook that shows the circumstance under which the error is produced- [link](https://db.tt/njJnLBQ1)

Comment: `zip`makes an iterator in Python 3. I would guess you already iterated over it for something before calling `dict()` - or perhaps you called dict on it twice and didn't keep the first result. If you want to use the `zip` object again, you have to call `zip` again to create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an issue with reusing zip results in the next cell...
Make dict of your zip in the first cell, and reuse it as is in next steps.

```
country_specialities_dict = dict(zip(countries, dishes))
```